# Sending email through CDOSYS but written in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am sick and tired of my hosting company. I think you can help me here.

I have simple need that I have my complete website written in Classic ASP. Now I want to have a page which sends email using CDOSYS. I wanted to have that script in ASP from my hosting company that what setting should i have. They always send me code in C#.

### here is they send always:

CDOSYS is part of the System.Web.Mail namespace and is installed by default on Windows 2000 and Windows XP platforms. It replaces CDONTS for sending SMTP email messages and can be used with our IIS 6 and IIS 7 Windows hosting accounts. The following code sample demonstrates how to create, format, and send email.

```
private void SendEmail()
{
const string SERVER = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
MailMessage oMail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
oMail.From = "emailaddress@domainname";
oMail.To = "emailaddress@domainname";
oMail.Subject = "Test email subject";
oMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html; // enumeration
oMail.Priority = MailPriority.High; // enumeration
oMail.Body = "Sent at: " + DateTime.Now;
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = SERVER;
SmtpMail.Send(oMail); 
oMail = null; // free up resources
 }
```

Here is my ASP which I written to use same thing but doesn't work:

```
Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration") 

objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields.Update 
With objCDOSYSMail
  .To       = strEmail
  .BCc       = "a@gmail.com"
  .Cc       = "b@gmail.com"
  .From     = "sales@b.com"
  .Subject  = "Thank you!"
  .HTMLBody = "Hello<br></br><h3>Thank you for your enquiry. <br/>"
Set objCDOSYSMail = Nothing 
Set objCDOSYSCon = Nothing
```

I don't know how to use their code.... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in a classic ASP page to send email with CDOSYS:

```
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set objFlds = objConf.Fields
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.your-site-url.com" 'your smtp server domain or IP address goes here
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 'default port for email
'uncomment next three lines if you need to use SMTP Authorization
'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "your-username"
'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "your-password"
'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
objFlds.Update
objMail.Configuration = objConf
objMail.FromName = "Your Name"
objMail.From = "your@address.com"
objMail.To = "destination@address.com"
objMail.Subject = "Email Subject Text"
objMail.TextBody = "The message of the email..."
objMail.Send
Set objFlds = Nothing
Set objConf = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
```